# Counting Lists and Adding to a new Dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm working with dictionaries and was wondering how I could output a dictionary where its key is the word that occurs in a given dictionary and its value is the number of times it occurs within that dictionary.

So say for example,

```
A = {'#1': ['Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red'], '#2': ['White', 'Purple', 'Purple', 'Red']}
B - []
for key in A:
    B.append(A[key])

>>> B
>>> [['Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red'], ['White', 'Purple', 'Purple', 'Red']]
```

After returning the respective values of the keys, I can now loop through each list of strings and flatten the list of values.

```
C = []
for sublist in B:
    for item in sublist:
        C.append(item)
```

I know that I need to count the number of times the certain strings occur in that list and then populate a dictionary with the key being the colour and the value being how many times it occurs. This part is mainly where I'm having difficulty.

Comment: Have a look at [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Take a look at pythons Counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c
['Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red', 'White', 'Purple', 'Purple', 'Red']
>>> Counter(c)
Counter({'Red': 2, 'Purple': 2, 'Yellow': 1, 'Blue': 1, 'White': 1})
```

Or make your own:

```
>>> d = {i: c.count(i) for i in c}
>>> d
{'Yellow': 1, 'Blue': 1, 'Red': 2, 'White': 1, 'Purple': 2}
```

Also you can make your `c` creation shorter:

```
c = []
for i in A.values():
    c.extend(i)

>>> c
['Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red', 'White', 'Purple', 'Purple', 'Red']
```

or:

```
c = [j for i in A.values() for j in i]

>>> c
['Yellow', 'Blue', 'Red', 'White', 'Purple', 'Purple', 'Red']
```